# How to interact with Cooca objects in an application without an API (Skype)

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, skype

I'm trying to make it possible for an application to interact with Skype for Mac, which would be fine except the Skype API is no longer supported (I've heard that it does work, but not reliably: they've replaced it with URI, which can't deal with messages, if I remember correctly). I'm *reasonably* sure that Skype for Mac uses the Cocoa framework, based on the fact that I can toggle Text-to-Speech and use the system autocorrect features in the text boxes.

It's most important that I'm able to send messages (because I can probably use the Notification Center to deal with receiving them), so I'm wondering if there's a way to use a tool like AppleScript to interact with the text boxes and send messages. If that's impossible, would you suggest a tool to use to simulate Skype and user input?

The entire project that I'm trying to do is to use Discord and Skype at the same time, so I planned to have a Discord bot sending data to my Skype wrapper application which runs on my home computer.

Sorry if this question is overly vague or nonsensical, I'm just having problems figuring out where to start with this project.

Comment: Take a look at Apple's [Accessibility API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'm sorry for not checking this sooner, I am but a student bogged down with finals. Will do!